# search for a specific row in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to verify my search box (html) using php code 
but in all times it gives all rows I dont know where is the problem

html code:

```
<form action="searchHotel.php" method="post">
<input value="Hotel's Name" type="text" name="Hotels_Name" id="dropdownlist" style="width:150px; hight:10px;">
</form>
</br>
<br/>
<button style = " margin-top:2%; position:relative;" type="button" onClick="location.href='searchHotel.php'" method="post" action="searchHotel.php">GO</button>
<br/><br/>
```

a peice of php code:

```
    //code
      echo $_POST['Hotels_Name'];
      $n = (string) $_POST['Hotels_Name'];
      $variable = (string)$n;
      $query = "SELECT * FROM facility WHERE name LIKE '%$variable%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sqlquery");
      $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
      echo $number;
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

I have already connected the database

Comment: If you want a specific row, I don't think `LIKE` is the term you need. Why not just check if `name = $variable`. NOTE: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and you should never pass user data directly into your queries that way.

Comment: There are tons of problems here. You don't need javascript on the button, just put it inside the form. Next, mysql is depreciated, use pdo or mysqli. Also, you need to sanitize user input!! Your script is wide open for mischief or worse.

Comment: @Grice I didn't say so because I want a peice of what the user entered in the text box so I used % %

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your html code use below code. In your code there is no proper form action onto form. So try below html code. Also try mysqli for database operations in php code.

```
<form action="searchHotel.php" method="post">
<input  type="text" name="Hotels_Name" id="dropdownlist" style="width:150px; hight:10px;">
<input style = " margin-top:2%; position:relative;" type="submit" value="GO" >
</form>
```